# Timing issue using `connect-mongo` and Mongoose with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connect-mongo

I am using [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) for my ExpressJS Session Store and [Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) for my DB connection and am having, what I will call, a timing issue with it. Here is my code:

**`dbservice.js`**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const debug = require('debug')('app:core:db:service');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const config = require('config');

const mongoDbUrl = config.mongodb_url;

const mongoDbOptions = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
};
(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, mongoDbOptions);
    debug(`Connected to ${chalk.green('MongoDB')}`);
  } catch (err) {
    debug(`${chalk.green('MongoDB')} connection ${chalk.red(`error`)}: ${err}`);
  }
})();
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (err) => {
  debug(`${chalk.green('MongoDB')} connection ${chalk.red(`error`)}: ${err}`);
});
// For nodemon restarts
process.once('SIGUSR2', () => {
  const msg = 'Nodemon Restart';
  db.close()
    .then(() => {
      debug(`${chalk.green('MongoDB')} connection ${chalk.red(`closed`)}: ${msg}`);
      process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      debug(err);
    });
});
const dbClient = db.getClient();

module.exports = dbClient;
```

**`app.js`**

```
const dbClient = require('dbService');

// Using Express Session with Google Cloud Datastore to securly store session/cookie information
app.use(
  session({
    // Using MongoDB as session store
    store: MongoStore.create({
      client: dbClient, // Use Mongoose for DB Conection
      ttl: 1800000, // Ages session out at 30 minutes
      autoRemove: 'native', // Uses MongoDB's native Time to Live (TTL) to expire and remove records
      },
    }),
  }),
);
```

This code works great when using a local, on-network instance of MongoDB because there is such a small delay in connecting to MongoDB that it works. However, when using MongoDB Atlas, there is a one to two second delay in connection. So, I suspect (what I thought was brilliant) my line of code `const dbClient = db.getClient()` in **`dbservice.js`** is failing with `connect-mongo` throwing out error:

```
(node:1148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db` because Mongoose is not connected.
```

As a novice, I have been struggling to try and solve this issue. I was trying to find a way to use `mongoose.connection.readyState` to wait until it returned a `1` for connected but have failed.

My question is this: Is there a better way for me to return `dbClient` with it properly waiting for Mongoose to connect to MongoDB? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking cues from [Nikita Mazur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14505115/nikita-mazur)'s response, I modified my **`dbservices.js`** to the following:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const debug = require('debug')('app:core:db:service');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const { mongoDbUrl } = require('../config/config');

const mongoDbOptions = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
};
async function dbConnection() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, mongoDbOptions);
    debug(`Connected to ${chalk.green('MongoDB')}`);
  } catch (err) {
    debug(`${chalk.green('MongoDB')} connection ${chalk.red(`error`)}: ${err}`);
  }
  return mongoose.connection.getClient();
}
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (err) => {
  debug(`${chalk.green('MongoDB')} connection ${chalk.red(`error`)}: ${err}`);
});
// For nodemon restarts
process.once('SIGUSR2', () => {
  const msg = 'Nodemon Restart';
  db.close()
    .then(() => {
      debug(`${chalk.green('MongoDB')} connection ${chalk.red(`closed`)}: ${msg}`);
      process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      debug(err);
    });
});

module.exports = dbConnection();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning Promise from your dbservice.js

```
(async () => {})()
```

makes no sense for async code

What your code should look like is

```js
const getDbClient = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, mongoDbOptions);
    debug(`Connected to ${chalk.green('MongoDB')}`);
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    return db.getClient()
  } catch (err) {
    debug(`${chalk.green('MongoDB')} connection ${chalk.red(`error`)}: ${err}`);
  }
}

function async start() {
  const client = await getDbClient()
    // Using Express Session with Google Cloud Datastore to securly store session/cookie         information
  app.use(
    session({
      // Using MongoDB as session store
      store: MongoStore.create({
        client: client, // Use Mongoose for DB Conection
        ttl: 1800000, // Ages session out at 30 minutes
        autoRemove: 'native', // Uses MongoDB's native Time to Live (TTL) to expire and        remove records
        },
      }),
    }),
  );
  // Here is server startup code.... app.listen etc.
}

start.then(() => console.log('started'))
```